# Getting datatables content via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, datatable

Currently I'm generating basic table with PHP

```
        <table id="list" class="display">   
            <thead>
                <tr id="hdr">
                    <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"/>  ID</th>
                    <th>Ref. No</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                    <th>Size</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Stack NO</th>
                    <th>Price</th> 
                    <th>Add Date</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM  `items` ORDER BY id DESC");
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                        echo '<tr url="?page=item&id=' . $row->id . '">
<td class="item_id"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" method="post" value="' . $row->id . '" class="checkbox"/>    ' . $row->id . '</td>
<td> ' . $row->refno . '</td>
<td style="text-align:center">' . $row->color . '</td>
<td style="text-align:center">' . $row->size . '</td>
<td style="text-align:center" id="qt">' . trim($row->qt) . '</td>
<td style="text-align:center">' . $row->stackno . '</td>
<td style="text-align:center">' . $row->price . '</td>
<td>' . date('d.m.Y', strtotime($row->add_date)) . '</td>
</tr>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Then applying datatables into this like that

```
 oTable= $('#list').dataTable( {       
        "bJQueryUI": true, 
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "aoColumns": [ 
        {
            "bSortable": false
        },
        null, null, null,null,null, null, null
        ]    
    } ).columnFilter({
        sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
        aoColumns: [    null, null, null,null,null, null, null,
        {
            type: "date-range"
        }
        ]

    });
```

There is very big problem:

Currently my table has about 2000 rows. It takes very long to generate and load whole table. (At first it generates then applieas datatables) How can I modify this script to get contents via ajax page-by-page?

Answer (score 1):

There are fully documented methods and examples in datatables API for using json data for dynamic tables using either local or server  source

Even the download package includes these examples

Comment: Agreed; all the examples are there. My first project with DataTables used server-side and I never thought of it as hidden; I looked for it and it was right there: http://datatables.net/usage/server-side

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you need to take advantage of Pagination. A [quick peak at the documentation](http://datatables.net/development/pagination) for dataTables shows that it provides inherit support for this.

There's a fully functional example that shows you exactly how they acheived pagination and can be [found here](http://live.datatables.net/#source).

Good luck.

Comment: It's not just pagination, it's the whole server-side functionality. Getting hung up in the details of pagination itself would be to miss out on everything else that's needed for server-side processing.